# Ao clicar no número de telefone ser redirecionado para Chamada

Tags: html, android

Gostaria que ao clicar em um número de telefone fosse redirecionado para as ligações no android conforme as imagens em anexo, ou seja a clico 1058 e ele redireciona para realizar a ligação no número, como é feito?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Exemplo `<a href="tel:55555"> chamar 5555</a>`

Comment: Deu certo amigo, obrigado por responder abs